# PHP values substraction

Tags: php, algorithm

Let's say I have an array with numeric values.

```
$expenses = array(10, 10, 10, 10, 5, 5, 2, 20);
```

And a numeric value that is altered inside a loop. Say this value is called $sub and is initialized as say 30.

What I want is inside the following nested loop to subsract each value of the expenses array from the $sub.

For example:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++){

//$sub = a whatever value; 

    for($j = 0; $j < count($expenses); $j++){

       if ( $expenses[$j] > 0 ){
            //the area for calculations to run
           $expenses[$j] = $sub - $expenses[$j];
         }
     }
 }
```

Results are:

```
Index 0: $expenses[0] = $sub - $expenses[0]; // 30-10=20

Index 1: $expenses[1] = $sub - $expenses[1]; // 30-10=20
```

...

When the nested loop finds the current array value that is **different** from the previous one

(i.e. index 4 and index 3 in the $expenses array), then the $sub must has the value of the last happened substraction in the loop, which is 20. When this is true, the main susbtraction must be 20-5.

While the current array value is the **same** with the previous one, then keep doing the 20-5 thing. So the deal is to keep in mind the substraction's result and adjust the $sub in order to do the substraction with an `$expenses` array value.
When the result of the substraction is negative or zero, then the execution must be terminated.

In our case, the final results after the first loop has ended execution are:

Index 0: 30-10=20

Index 1: 30-10=20

Index 2: 30-10=20

Index 3: 30-10=20

Index 4: 20-5=15

Index 5: 20-5=15

Index 6: 15-2=13

Index 7: 13-20=-7

So i want to update the array and the substraction value.

Comment: Could you please more directly and explicitly describe the result you desire?

Comment: So keep the last value(s) in an extra variable and compare in each iteration. This really isn't too terribly complicated; if you can't figure it out yourself you should seriously reconsider this programming thing... Try to find the solution yourself, for your own sake!

Comment: Ok forgive me for failing to code this algorighm. I tried to find the solution for quite a time but with no luck.

Comment: Your final output should be `13-20` not `15-20` ...

Comment: I edited this topic a few times in order to help you understand the problem. Thanks for the input...

Comment: See answer below  ....

Answer (score 2):

All you need is : `CachingIterator`

```
$ci = new CachingIterator(new ArrayIterator($expenses));
foreach($ci as $k => $item) {
    $diff = $sub - $item;
    printf("Index %d: %d-%d = %d\n", $k, $sub, $item, $diff);
    if ($item != $ci->getInnerIterator()->current()) {
        $sub = $diff;
    }
}
```

Output

```
Index 0: 30-10 = 20
Index 1: 30-10 = 20
Index 2: 30-10 = 20
Index 3: 30-10 = 20
Index 4: 20-5 = 15
Index 5: 20-5 = 15
Index 6: 15-2 = 13
Index 7: 13-20 = -7
```

[Live DEMO](http://eval.in/31721)

Comment: If the array has more values than the example, the execution does not end if the $sub becomes 0 or negative. Also, the array does not get updated. The results are only displayed in the screen,

Comment: You can end it yourself if you want ....

Comment: Ok, the important thing is to also update the array.

Comment: I don't work for you .. you should at least say thank you before given me additional task on how you should updated your array ...

Comment: Thanks for answering, but this is no additional task. Please read again my question, if you like. I am trying another solution myself for hours, so you are not alone, don't worry.